# Trying to call Microsoft Graph API in Java after retrieving Access token from Angular app

Tags: java, jwt, microsoft-graph-api

I have tried to follow some of the examples online, but they are not very helpful and the official Microsoft documentation can be somewhat confusing and all over the place.

I have the token, which includes the nonce in the header.

I have added in the Microsoft Graph dependency in my pom.xml file and everything is set up, but I am not sure how to actually implement the method using the access token and make the calle to get a the signed in user info for example.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

I have set up my app in Azure already and added in the API permissions.

any help or guidance in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to the example of signed-in user request, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example-2-signed-in-user-request).

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

// for "/me" endpoint    
User user = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get(); 

// for "/users/{id | userPrincipalName}" endpoint
// User user = graphClient.users("{id}").buildRequest().get()
```

Get authProvider with accessToken, refer to this [article](https://medium.com/xebia-engineering/java-use-microsoft-graph-api-to-access-sharepoint-sites-1a26427c9b83):

```
public IGraphServiceClient getAuthProvider() {
    IAuthenticationProvider mAuthenticationProvider;

    try {
        String accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        mAuthenticationProvider = request -> request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("Could not create a graph client: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return GraphServiceClient.builder()
                             .authenticationProvider(mAuthenticationProvider)
                             .buildClient();
}
```

For more information, [Make API calls using the Microsoft Graph SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=java) with Java.

Comment: Thank You! That helped me alot

Comment: After adding a bunch of heavy dependencies like MS Graph and Azure Identity SDK, I still had to resort to crafting pure HTTP POST calls in JAX-RS for requesting AcessToken and overriding the authentication provider for the simplest authentication mechanism of all times. So thank you for this!